# How to investigate/fix: ambiguous import: found package cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata in multiple modules

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, grpc-gateway

When I do a go mod tidy (go v1.19), I am receiving the following error.  I do see both packages in my go pkg directory.  I assume that v1.6.1 is the most current version and is the one to keep.  If this is true, how do I determine who is dragging in the older v0.34.0 version and correct it?  I'd appreciate your suggestions.

Thank you for your time and interest,
Mike

```
github.com/abc/runimage/v5/core/service imports
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/auth tested by
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/auth.test imports
    google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/oauth imports
    golang.org/x/oauth2/google imports
    cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata: ambiguous import: found package cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata in multiple modules:
    cloud.google.com/go v0.34.0 (/Users/mike/Go/pkg/mod/cloud.google.com/go@v0.34.0/compute/metadata)
    cloud.google.com/go/compute v1.6.1 (/Users/mike/Go/pkg/mod/cloud.google.com/go/compute@v1.6.1/metadata)
make: *** [tidy] Error 1
```

```
// go.mod 

module github.com/abc/runimage/v5

go 1.19

require (
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware v1.3.0
    github.com/labstack/gommon v0.3.1
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20220805133916-01dd62135a58
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.48.0
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.28.1
)

require (
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2 v2.11.2
    github.com/joho/godotenv v1.4.0
)

require (
    github.com/decred/dcrd/dcrec/secp256k1/v4 v4.0.0-20210816181553-5444fa50b93d // indirect
    github.com/go-resty/resty/v2 v2.7.0 // indirect
    github.com/goccy/go-json v0.9.4 // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.2 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/errwrap v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror v1.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/lestrrat-go/backoff/v2 v2.0.8 // indirect
    github.com/lestrrat-go/blackmagic v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/lestrrat-go/httpcc v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/lestrrat-go/iter v1.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx v1.2.18 // indirect
    github.com/lestrrat-go/option v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.12 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.14 // indirect
    github.com/okta/okta-jwt-verifier-golang v1.3.1 // indirect
    github.com/patrickmn/go-cache v0.0.0-20180815053127-5633e0862627 // indirect
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1 // indirect
    github.com/valyala/bytebufferpool v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/valyala/fasttemplate v1.2.1 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20220622213112-05595931fe9d // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20220624214902-1bab6f366d9e // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220610221304-9f5ed59c137d // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.7 // indirect
)
```

Comment: What's your go.mod file content?

Comment: Hello Guillaume,  Thank you for your response and interest.  I've updated this question with the go.mod file's content.  We are using go mod vendoring, too.

Comment: Did you try to explicitly define the metadata dependency in the go.mod?

Answer (score 10):

Try `go get cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata` and then `go mod tidy`

Comment: Still getting `ambiguous import: found package cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata in multiple modules:
 cloud.google.com/go v0.26.0 (.../pkg/mod/cloud.google.com/go@v0.26.0/compute/metadata)
 cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata v0.2.3 (.../pkg/mod/cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata@v0.2.3)`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error as you, and I resolved it by deleting the `cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata` dependency from my `go.mod` file. It isn't needed after a certain version of the google cloud api.

After I did that, I ran `go mod tidy` and everything started to work again.

Hope this helps :)